# sphinx perfect match problem?

Tags: php, sphinx

i am new to Sphinx .

```php
<?php
    include('sphinxapi.php');
    $cl = new SphinxClient();
    $cl->SetServer('localhost',9312);
    //$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
    //$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
    //$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
    $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_PHRASE);
    $cl->SetArrayResult(true);
    $cl->SetLimits(0, 100); 
    $result = $cl->Query("&name one boy","abc_index");

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    exit;
?>
```

i need only "`one boy`" word matching records which match mode is correct for that?

i am already using `SPH_MATCH_PHRASE`  mode. But it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <?php    
    include('sphinxapi.php'); 
    $cl = new SphinxClient();  
    $cl->SetServer('localhost',9312);
    $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
    $cl->SetArrayResult(true);
    $cl->SetLimits(0, 100);  
    //this is for perfect match mode
    $searchkey='one boy';
    $sphinxQry = '@(name) '. '"'.$searchkey.'"';
    $result = $cl->Query($sphinxQry,"abc_index");

   echo "<pre>";   

   print_r($result);  
   exit; ?>
```

Comment: If you are using some kind of stemming, you would get a match for 'one boys' as well. I think...